# Mootools detectar movimento da página

Tags: rolamento, mootools

Como faço para detectar quando uma página é rolada até um determinado ponto, e quando atingir esse ponto efectuar uma determinada ação.
Ou seja, usando MooTools, como o *event scroll*, alterar o estilo de um elemento.

[Vejam um exemplo parecido](http://jsfiddle.net/chicote/zzspxd4o/3/), mas este basta fazer *scroll*. eu quero que aconteça algo deste gênero mas só quando rolamos a página por exemplo a 1500px do topo.

Answer (score 3):

Já consegui..

De qualquer forma fica aqui, pode alguem necessitar.

```
var posts;
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    posts = $$('.post');
})

window.addEvent('scroll', function(e){
    var altura = window.getScroll().y;
    posts.each(function (post) {
        if (post.getPosition().y > altura + 400) return;
        post.fade('in');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chicote/r0fuuzhj/

Comment: Boa! `+1` fico sempre contente de ver mais gente a usar o MooTools.